# Javascript and Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener, microsoft-edge-extension

I am making a chrome extension and I want to add an overlay navigation, but I need Javascript for that, and when I put the Javascript in, chrome told me I cannot use inline JS.

So then I used an event listener, but then it told me that it cannot read the even listener.

The navigation's HTML:

```
<div id="Navigation" class="Overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closebtn">&times;</a>
    <div class="Links">
        <a href="popup.html"> Home </a>
        <a href="colors.html"> Colors </a>
        <a href="links.html"> Links </a>
    </div>
</div>
<span id="menuIcon">
    <div class="menuPart"></div>
    <div class="menuPart"></div>
    <div class="menuPart"></div>
</span>
```

The navigation's EventListener (the JS):

```
document.getElementById("menuIcon").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("Navigation").style.width = "100%"
});

document.getElementById("closebtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("Navigation").style.width = "0%"
});
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Answer (score 0):

In a Chrome extension, you should use an external JavaScript file to add event listeners and manipulate the DOM.

Create a new JavaScript file, and name it something like overlay_nav.js or whatever you'd prefer.

Paste your JavaScript code into the .js file like the following example:

```
// overlay_nav.js 
document.getElementById("menuIcon").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
enter code heredocument.getElementById("Navigation").style.width = "100%"; 
}); 

document.getElementById("closebtn").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
document.getElementById("Navigation").style.width = "0%"; });
```

Now you'll be able to link the .js file using a  tag before the closing  tag. See the example below:

```
<!-- popup.html or your relevant HTML file -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Your other HTML head content goes here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your navigation and menu icon HTML goes here -->

    **<!-- Add the .js file here -->
    <script src="overlay_nav.js"></script>**
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you'll have to place the .js script in the same folder as the .html script

Comment: Do I add the <script src="..."></script> in the <body> or <head>?

Comment: The following: <script src="..."></script> should be added in the body and not the head. But I would suggest trying both (head and body) just to see how each option works out. I tend to work this way since you'll learn more from your mistakes. In programming, trial & error is the best method to learn. That is if you're interested in learning :)